# Hybris Facet Navigation

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Does anyone have an idea how to add additional attributes in my Facet Navigation which is displayed on the product list page? So far I can choose only price ranges, but I want to add brands and other filters, do you know how to maintain it via the hMC? I think it has something to do with the solr configurations, but I'm fairly new to hybris...

Comment: Read the forum and wiki where this is covered

Comment: HMC > System > Facet Config. Look in sampledata extension for sample impexes, I think there may be impex in yaccelerator as well.

Comment: use solr.impex file to create new facet attribute. look apparel or electronic store slor.impex file also how they had created. Sometime you need to update facet index also through hmc.

Answer (score 5):

Best way is to have a look at what is provided out of the box, under for example the electronic store, open the file **/electronicsstore/resources/electronicsstore/import/sampledata/stores/electronics/solr.impex**

Inside you will find facets definition, for example this is a facet definition for Megapixles :

```
INSERT_UPDATE SolrIndexedProperty;solrIndexedType(identifier) unique=true];name[unique=true];type(code);sortableType(code);currency[default=false];localized[default=false];multiValue[default=false];facet[default=false];facetType(code);facetSort(code);priority;visible;fieldValueProvider;customFacetSortProvider;rangeSets(name);$classAttributeAssignment
;electronicsProductType;Megapixel, 63          ;double;; ;    ; ;true;MultiSelectOr;Custom;1000;true;commerceClassificationPropertyValueProvider;numericFacetSortProviderDesc;MegaPixelRange;57:::Megapixel, 63::::
```

**What you need to remember is that for any customized types other that literal/Atomic you would need to create your own provider. For every basic Literal/Atomic type (String,double,integer,boolean) the commerceClassificationPropertyValueProvider would be enough.**

Answer (score 1):

```
There are two ways to do this
1.Impex: Go to solr.impex file and add the facet(=true) property to SolrIndexedProperty type header
Ex: INSERT_UPDATE SolrIndexedProperty;solrIndexedType(identifier)[unique=true];name[unique=true];type(code);sortableType(code);currency[default=false];localized[default=false];multiValue[default=false];facet[default=false];facetType(code);facetSort(code);priority;visible;fieldValueProvider;customFacetSortProvider;rangeSets(name);$classAttributeAssignment
;electronicsProductType;Megapixel, 63 ;double;; ; ; ;true;MultiSelectOr;Custom;1000;true;commerceClassificationPropertyValueProvider;numericFacetSortProviderDesc;MegaPixelRange;57:::Megapixel, 63::::


2.hmc: hmc --> System --> Facet Search --> SolrItemType --> select solritemtype --> add solrindexproperties --> select facet checkbox to true
```

Answer (score 1):

For adding more product attributes like brand, name, any_other_attribute, you should go to:

> HMC>System>Facet Search>Indexed Type

. search with blank field.

Now choose `<Index TYPE>` like **product. Now you can see all product attributes in a table. And there are some checkboxes around them.

These are search setting for attributes inside the product.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't just simply add your new **solrIndexedProperty** to **solrIndexedType** via HMC and hope it will work, it wont work, because you have to maintain some other points:

1. If your new attribute is a complex object for example (Brand, Price, Unite,...) you have to create a **Value Provider** to transform that object to a simple primitive data (string, int, double,...) and send it to solr to be indexed, for example, Brand to Brand.name and Price to Price.formattedValue...
2. Then you have to expose your new **solrIndexedProperty** value to the front side via **FacetPopulator**.

Answer (score 0):

If you have hybris wiki access then you can easily finish this. In commerce trails they have covered about facet search. Kindly have a look at it.
https://wiki.hybris.com/display/R5T/Tweaking+SolR+Attributes+and+Facets